# How do I solve $\lim_{x \to \infty} x(e^{(1/x)}-1)$ without L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I don't have experience with L'Hopital Rule nor series and thats what most solution are, is there is other method can be used to solve that limit? i thought about trying to use first principle of derivative but i dont know where to begin. i need some help to guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Why not become experience with L'Hopital?

Comment: @DietrichBurde we're not allowed to use in our exams because its not in   program for this year.

Comment: Then have a look at MSE about methods without L'Hopital, e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939702/limits-without-lhopitals-rule?rq=1). Did you see the related questions on the right margin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is precisely $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\exp\left(\frac 1x\right) - 1}{\frac 1x} = \lim_{u \to 0^{+}} \frac{\exp\left(u \right) - 1}{u}$$

Does that remind you of some derivative?